# Language directory rewrite to root Wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, wordpress

I am trying to achieve following:
I have language directories eg.
mysite.com/en/
mysite.com/th/
and so on.
I want main site/files from root directory will be diplayed when someone enters
mysite.com/en/something.html

So mysite.com/en/something.html actually diplaying files from
mysite.com/something.html

Comment: "diplaying files from mysite.com/something.html" - Are you dealing with physical files? But you've referenced WordPress?

Comment: Wordpress is installed in root. I am not sure maybe I need Wordpress url rewrite instead of htaccess at all to achieve this.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is multilingual website and I need normal language directories displayed in url instead of using simply in the end of each url ?lang=en I am not sure at all this si a right way to do it...if anyone has been in this point maybe guide me to the right direction

Comment: "I want main site/files from root directory" - If this is a WordPress site then there are no physical files from the root to be served. The URLs are presumably entirely "virtual" and handled by WordPress. I think you are going to need to do this in WordPress, not Apache/`.htaccess`. The WordPress stack may be a better fit for this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/